# bbPress plugin add pin icon for top five topics

Tags: php, wordpress, bbpress

I want to add Pin icon for top or popular five topics? Could anyone can help me out this issue?

I have found the solution top five forum below is code:

```
function rk_top_five_view() {
bbp_register_view( 'top-five', __( '5 Most Popular Topics' ), array( 
    'meta_key' => '_bbp_reply_count',
    'posts_per_page' => '5' ,
    ' max_num_pages' => '1', 
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num' ),
false );
}

add_action( 'bbp_register_views', 'rk_top_five_view' );
```

But how I can apply for add pin icon?

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use Font Awesome CSS to add pin icon. For example,

```
.post-type-archive-forum .forum-recent-topics-content .forum-recent-topics-content-name {
position: relative;
padding: 5px 15px;
padding-left: 40px;
padding-bottom: 1px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.post-type-archive-forum .forum-recent-topics-content .forum-recent-topics-content-name:before {
content: "\f08d";
font-family: FontAwesome;
position: absolute;
padding: 15px 15px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
font-size: 15px;
color: #513a24;
}
```

Hope this will helps you.
For example visit. this [URL](http://guitaretudes.com/forums/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is only for latest topics, I want to get most popular topics on top and add pin icon for top 5 only.

Answer (score 0):

To check which questions are most popular,first of all you have to code to get count seen questions.

For this, overwrite template of topic to theme folder. Path is "wp-content/plugins/bbpress/templates/default/bbpress/content-single-topic.php"
Copy this file from plugin to theme and add code in top of the file.

```
$count = get_post_meta(bbp_get_topic_id(),'wp_dp_topic_seen_count',true);

if($count == ""){
    $count = 0;
}
$count1 = $count+1;
update_post_meta(bbp_get_topic_id(),'topic_seen_count',$count1);
```

Now you have topics with seen count. You can add following code to get most 5 popular topics.

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'  => 'reply',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'meta_key' => 'topic_seen_count',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'   => 'DESC',
    );
$posts_array = get_posts( $args );
```